# Embedded analog of CouchDB, same as sqlite for SQL Server

Tags: ruby, database, document-oriented-db

I like an idea of document oriented databases like CouchDB. I am looking for simple analog.

My requirements is just:

1. persistance storage for schema less data;
2. some simple in-proc quering;
3. good to have transactions and versioning;
4. ruby API;
5. map/reduce is aslo good to have;
6. should work on shared hosting

What I do not need is REST/HTTP interfaces (I will use it in-proc). Also I do not need all scalability stuff.

Comment: I am still searching... In background...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple solution would be [PStore](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/pstore/rdoc/classes/PStore.html) from Ruby's Standard Library. It should meet almost all your requirements:

1. PStore stores Ruby object hierarchies in files, so you can easily use the Hash-like structures, you would have in CouchDB
2. You can access the contents of the PStore with a simple API
3. It has transactions, but no versions as far as I know
4. yes
5. You can use Ruby's map and inject functions
6. All you need is access to the file system

Example:

Insert data into the store:

```
require 'pstore'
store = PStore.new("/tmp/store")
store.transaction do
  store["products"] = [{:name => "Test", :price => 100}
                       {:name => "Bla", :price => 120}
                       {:name => "Oink", :price => 300}]
end
```

Query the sum of the prices of all products:

```
store.transaction do
  store['products'].map {|p| p[:price]}.inject {|sum, p| sum + p}
end
```

More information in this [blog-post](http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/engineyard/~3/En_oJvnhrtg/)

Comment: Hm, yes seems that this is what I need. I will definetly try this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/index.html).  It does everything you list except for map/reduce.